# Highcharts: minRange=1 creates -1 and 1 on a chart with one data point

Tags: highcharts

I am playing with a chart with a one data point.

Here is the jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mddc/mfwyoj7j/7/

I notice that if I add

```
minRange: 1
```

-1 or 1 will show up on both sides of the data point on the X axis.

I am new to Highcharts. What does minRange=1 mean here? If it is useless, then it should not create any problems, right?

Is this a bug in Highcharts?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See highcharts API doc here: `http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.minRange`

> minRange: the minimum range to display. The entire axis will not be allowed to
>   span over a smaller interval than this. For example, for a datetime
>   axis the main unit is milliseconds. If minRange is set to 3600000, you
>   can't zoom in more than to one hour.

So it is used to limit the zoom-in: you will not be able to zoom if the xAxis display less than `1`

Comment: Nicolas, thanks for your input. That is what I understand about minRange=1. So, it is useless by understanding, which I mentioned in the post. But Highcharts' behavior is weird for a useless setting, correct?

Comment: It is useless for your 1 point data, but it is normal that if the `minRange` is set to 1, it will zoom out compared to the case where this parameter is not supplied, in order to match the parameter. And here it displayed a range of... 2: if you test with different values, it seems that it displays a `minRange + 1` range